# Allow creation of new content type just like taxonomy

Tags: 6, nodes

I like the way the Taxonomy module allows users to create a new taxonomy term "on-the-fly." Are there any modules that can also allow users to create new "content" of a node "on-the-fly"? Here is my scenario:

- Content Type A (Companies)
- Content Type B (Users)

Users have node reference to Companies, so every time a new user is added, a company is selected for this user.

I need to be able to just add a user directly on a Drupal 6 site, and if a company does not exist, I can also add a new company right there on the same page while adding that user. This works very similary with taxonomy, but I don't want to reference a taxonomy since Content Type A has also a lot of fields attached to it, which a taxonomy cannot do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the [Node Reference Create](http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate) module?